# Get notified if a restricted folder/drive is being accessed?

Tags: windows, windows-server

If I setup a network folder and then share that folder with certain groups/people only, is it possible to get notified either via email or some other forms of notification that a folder was accessed or if someone is trying to access that folder?

For example, I have PersonA as an admin, but personA does not have access to folderB. However, due to personA's admin privileges', they can still browse the folder.

Is it possible to setup something to notify certain people/groups if the folder was accessed by someone not assigned to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up Windows Auditing for a folder to generate event log entries.

1. **Set up Auditing on folder**
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder
   This is the first step.
   Only files and folders where you set up Auditing will generate events in EventLog.
   **Navigation:** `File/Folder --> Properties --> Security --> Advanced --> Auditing`
   **Add:** `Read` for all read activities (open folder, read attributes, open file) for the chosen user/group, or use `List Folder/ Read data` for more restrictive auditing.
2. **Set up Audit Policy (GPO)**
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-file-system
   Then you need `Audit File System` to be set to `Success` (don't use `Audit File Share`!)
   **Navigation:** `gpedit.msc --> Computer Configuration --> Windows Settings --> Security Settings --> Advanced Audit Policy - Configuration --> System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy --> Object Access --> "Audit File System"`

> File System
>
> This policy setting allows you to audit user attempts to access file system objects. A security audit event is generated only for objects that have system access control lists (SACL) specified, and only if the type of access requested, such as Write, Read, or Modify and the account making the request match the settings in the SACL. For more information about enabling object access auditing, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=122083.
>
> If you configure this policy setting, an audit event is generated each time an account accesses a file system object with a matching SACL. Success audits record successful attempts and Failure audits record unsuccessful attempts.
> If you do not configure this policy setting, no audit event is generated when an account accesses a file system object with a matching SACL.
>
> Note: You can set a SACL on a file system object using the Security tab in that object's Properties dialog box.
>
> Volume: Depends on how the file system SACLs are configured.

3. **Notification**
   Now, that part is a bit tricky, because each read access does not only create one event entry, but several ones.
   Furthermore, the event log filter does not allow wildcard searches, which is required to get accurate results, because we should not only filter for directory `C:\temp`, we should filter `C:\temp\*` to get access to subfolders as well.

   This could be achieved with a PowerShell script, which runs as a scheduled task and reads the event log and does a post-filtering.

   You have to replace the username `SubjectUserName` and the target directory path respectively.

   With PowerShell you can then combine it in a structured single (html) mail and send it to everybody you want.

```powershell
<#
resources:
    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7.1
    https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/Creating-Get-WinEvent-queries-with-FilterHashtable?view=powershell-7.1
#>

using namespace System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader

$keywords  = [StandardEventKeywords]@(
    [StandardEventKeywords]::AuditSuccess
    [StandardEventKeywords]::AuditFailure
)

$logLevels = [int[]]@(
    [StandardEventLevel]::LogAlways
    [StandardEventLevel]::Critical
    [StandardEventLevel]::Error
    [StandardEventLevel]::Warning
    [StandardEventLevel]::Informational
    [StandardEventLevel]::Verbose
)

$eventFilter = @{ 
    LogName         = 'Security'
    Level           = $logLevels
    StartTime       = (Get-Date) - [timespan]::new(1, 0, 0) # last hour
    EndTime         = (Get-Date)
    ID              = '4663' # "Audit File System"
    Keywords        = $keywords.value__
    SubjectUserName = '<username>'
}

# read event log
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $eventFilter 



# we have to do post-filter for the directory path, 
# because the eventFitler does not allow searching with wildcards or starts-with
# see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/advanced-xml-filtering-in-the-windows-event-viewer#xpath-10-limitations

$directoryPath = 'C:\temp'

# make it fit for regex by escaping and appending optional backslash
$directoryPathPattern = [regex]::Escape($directoryPath) -replace '(\\|\/)+$', '(?:\\.+)?'
foreach ($event in $events) {
    # serialization + deserialization due to all missing property names (like 'ObjectName')
    $eventXml = [xml]$event.toXml()

    # look for directory path in named event data field 'ObjectName'
    $directoryMatch = $eventXml.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object { 
        $_.Name -eq 'ObjectName' -and $_.'#text' -match "`^$directoryPathPattern`$" 
    }

    if ($null -ne $directoryMatch) {
        $event
    }
}
```